# Forge AR/VR Toolkit Unable to get scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge, virtual-reality, forge

I have been trying to use forge AR/VR toolkit to fetch Revit model from BIM360 to Unity.
I have created a scene, posted the job and got the manifest(shows status complete).

In Unity (Vr. 2019.2.12f1), I import the forge unity package. It shows the following warnings.

[image]

If i skip through these warnings, enter the model URN, Access Token and Scene ID, and hit play, nothing gets loaded. 
I get error 422: Unprocessable Entity. However it also says scene loaded in 2.something seconds. Image shown below.

I tried the same workflow once earlier and it worked. I am not sure what the issue is now.
[image]

Ok, so I just tried urn, token etc from forge sample gallery. It works. So clearly there is a problem with my workflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can encourage other users to help you on your issue by providing a [minimal, reproducible and working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

When [creating scenes](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1#/ARVR-Toolkit/create_scene) from BIM360 models, make sure to include the `project_id` and `version_id` fields:

[image: Scene creation API]

Comment: Shameless plug: as an alternative, try taking a look at https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils. It's basically a local alternative to AR/VR Toolkit. You can use it as an npm module or as a command line tool to convert Forge models to [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF) which has a large ecosystem of tools, incl. Unity importers.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. But I did include project id and version id while creating scene.

Comment: Hi @Aayush, can you share a curl command of what you are trying to do, so we can analyse what is missing.